# Tosfos Rabbeinu Peretz on Sanhedrin

Tags: talmud-gemara, jewish-books, commentaries

I saw in Rav Steinsaltz's commentary on Sanhedrin 17a a reference to Tosafos Rabbeinu Peretz. Is Tosafos Rabbeinu Peretz on Sanhedrin available online anywhere?

Comment: @robev It’s cited in Steinsaltz Sanhedrin (17a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not been able to locate any **Tosafos Rabbeinu Peretz** on Sanhedrin. Indeed, for what it's worth, [Wikipedia](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%95_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A5) reports that we don't have his comments on Sanhedrin.

However, thanks to @Dov, I was able to locate the existence of [**Tosafos Rabbeinu Peretz HaShalem**](https://www.nli.org.il/en/books/NNL_ALEPH990013648630205171/NLI). There, the book description states that they have printed from manuscripts the comments of **Rabbeinu Peretz** on other *masechtos* than what was previously available. They write that for Sanhedrin, they collected comments from the *sefer* [**Chamra VeChayii**](https://hebrewbooks.org/19216), written by [**Rav Chaim Benveniste**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Benveniste), a 17th century Turkish Rav.

His *sefer* seems to be a **Shita Mekubetzes** style work, collecting the insights of *Rishonim* on Sanhedrin. It's not a book dedicated to **Rabbeinu Peretz**. Indeed, a search on Otzar HaChochmah yielded only 16 references to his comments in the entire work. Furthermore, they're only attributed to the **students** of **Rabbeinu Peretz**.

I assume this is what **Rav Steinsaltz** *zt"l* is referring to. If so, the two comments of **Tosafos Talmidei Rabbeinu Peretz** on 17a can be read [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19216&st=&pgnum=245&hilite=) (bottom left, ד"ה אלא) and [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19216&st=&pgnum=246) (top right, ד"ה נגבית). If you have access to Otzar HaChochmah, an easier to read print of these comments can be viewed [here](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=144923&pagenum=407).

Answer (score 0):

On the Otzar HaChochma website you can access the Oz Vehadar Murchevet edition of Sanhedrin [here](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=602502&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=16000787611391382&pagenum=1) which has the Tosafos Rabbeinu Peretz at the back (as detailed on page 8, second column on the left, first bold line) - however as it is beyond the free allowance you would have to pay to access the whole sefer.

Comment: Oz VeHadar doesn't have Tosafos Rabbeinu Peretz on Sanhedrin. In the back is only Tosafos HaRosh. I wonder if it even exists...

Comment: This was the Murchevet version which according to pg.8 does include the Tosafos Rabbeinu Peretz?

Comment: Every volume of Oz VeHadar has the exact same details pages at the beginning. That doesn't mean every volume has it.

Comment: @Robev - there is a tosafos rabbeinu peretz on Sanhedrin - the content of the full set on shas is specified here. Refer to Volume 5 - https://www.nli.org.il/en/books/NNL_ALEPH990013648630205171/NLI

Comment: In which case - does this now render my answer correct - and if so, I would appreciate the downvote being removed pls

Comment: Your answer is still incorrect as Oz Vehadar does not include Tosafos Rabbeinu Peretz on Sanhedrin. I checked.

Comment: Note: Your link is an impressive find. If you read their notes they say that the pieces from Sanhedrin were collected from the sefer חמרא וחיי. It seems to be a 17th century Shita Mekubetzes style sefer on Sanhedrin. If you look at that sefer, he only ever quotes from the "Talmidei Rabbeinu Peretz", or "Tosafos Talmidei Rabbeinu Peretz". He only does this 17 times, which isn't really enough for its own sefer. I'm not sure if this is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification